# N power n i-e n^n is polynomial or not ? Is there any polynomial difference between n^2 and n^n?

Tags: algorithm, math, master-theorem

Is `n` to the power `n` (i-e `n^n`) a polynomial? Can   `T(n) = 2T(n/2) + n^n` be solved using the master method?

Comment: No, polynomials have constant integer exponents, your exponent is variable.

Comment: So can we solve this question using masters Metthod , If yes which case is this?

Comment: No, you can't. But you get `T(n)/n = T(n/2)/(n/2) + n^(n-1)` which can be easily iterated and `n^(n-1)` clearly dominates the following terms `(n/2)^(n/2-1), (n/4)^(n/4-1)` in the sum so at worst you get `T(n)=O(log(n)*n^n)` and with some better arguments perhaps also `T(n)=O(n^n)`.

Answer (score 3):

It's not only not polynomial, it's also worse than factiorial. O(n^n) dominates O(n!). Also in the masters method f(n) must be polynomial, so you can not use it.